Power consumption question
I am currently trying to run an RPI 4B off a simple UPS cable I made from a power bank. How many Mah of power energy will it take to run at 30-50% of its maximum power per minute, so I can calculate how long the power will last?

M is mega ... m is milli ... A is amps ... h is hour

how is 30-50% per minute different from 30-50% per hour or just 30-50%?

Power is measured in Watts.

at 30-50% of what?

Are you sure it's actually a UPS?  Many power banks take long enough to switch from charging to discharging, that they drop out the Pi in the meantime.  It would take two converters to keep it online constantly, but most only have one that needs to shut down, switch roles, and start back up again.  Meanwhile, the external ports are unpowered.
